# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**My code:**

```py
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.guild_only()
async def owner_mention(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.owner.mention)
```

**Error:**

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> 'mention'

Comment: `ctx.guild.owner` is None so you cannot get the `mention` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're somr changes in `Intents`. Intents are like permissions. You need to define it for getting-sending messages to channels, members etc.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

For more information, you can check [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents).